# Preloading all images when app starts

Tags: java, android, static, bitmap, preloader

I'm attempting to make a simple game of Pairs for Android.

**Program Structure**

Menu.java (Menu activity initially loaded)

Game.java (Game activity, started by Menu) 
GameThread.java (Handles gameloop, calls render process in GameView) 
GameView.java (Handles all drawing to the screen)

Graphics.java (Stores loaded images)

**The Problem**

The problem is that loading all the bitmaps I require for the Game activity takes up to 2 seconds, as there are many images required to animate a set of 15 cards. In order to avoid a large loading time between the Menu and Game activities I was thinking of preloading all of the bitmaps required into the Graphics class, in a new thread when the app first starts (Menu activity), and showing some sort of loading animation.

Then as I can't pass the Graphics store from the Menu activity to the Game activity I would need to make it a static object in the Menu activity in order to access it from the Game activity (using Menu.graphics...). Is this a terrible way of doing it? I always thought using static objects was a bad idea? What other options do I have?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use the [AsncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this. There is also nice into article called [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) on the main Android doc site.

Comment: Thanks, AsyncTask definitely seems useful. As for using the preloaded resources from another activity, is it acceptable to just make the object storing the Graphics static, or is there a better way of doing it (as I can't pass the Graphics object between activities)?

Comment: Thanks! Can I just ask the best way to store my images? I guess if I use an array to point at R.drawable.someAsset, that's actually just storing a pointer not the image. Do the images all need loading into bitmaps?

Also, the resources which are used for imageViews which are in the xml layouts, how do I make it so the xml layout pulls the resource that is already loaded rather than loading a new instance? Do I have to start dynamically adding the images through the code, or is there a way to reference an image from the singleton in the XML?

Comment: Sounds like a new and separate question.